# Permisos de petición y respuesta WebSocket, socket io en Swift

Tags: swift, websocket

soy nuevo en el desarrollo con swift y tengo un problema.
he colocado en el info.plist la propiedad app transform security  settings en allow  arbitrary loads tengo entendido que sirve para permitir cualquier tipo de petición y respuesta.
En socket io tengo el siguiente ejemplo de la documentación.

```
import SocketIO

let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket
socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {(data, ack) in
        print("socket connected")
    }
    let socketData = ["String": "serviceAlive"] as [String : Any]
    socket.emit("user", socketData)
socket.on("user") {data, ack in
        print(data)

    }
socket.connect()
```

En websocketswift tengo lo siguiente

```
let ws = WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/Sockets-war/message")

        ws.event.open = {
            print("opened")
        }
        ws.event.close = { code, reason, clean in
            print("close")
        }
        ws.event.error = { error in
            print("error \(error)")
        }
        ws.event.message = { message in
            if let text = message as? String {
                print("recv: \(text)")
            }
        }
```

Pero en ambos casos solo consigo que en el servidor me muestre que ha sido conectado pero no emite y consume nada.
Ambos casos WebSocket y socket io los he consumido con javascript y funciona perfectamente, solo en swift falla.
utilizo swift 4.2, xcode 10, socket io 14.0.0 y de swiftweb 13.4.0

Comment: Cuál es la falla que tienes en Swift? Te muestra algún error en el log del Xcode?